# Are linear programming algorithms faster than quadratic programming algorithms?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constrained-optimization

I have an objective function that I can write either in quadratic programming (QP) such as 
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N C_{ij}^2$$
or as an LP problem
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N |C_{ij}|$$
which can be done by splitting $C_{ij}$ into two parts $C_{ij} = C_{ij}^+ + C_{ij}^-$ and imposing $C_{ij}^{+}>0$ and $C_{ij}^{-}>0$. This doubles the number of optimisation variables.

Both approaches will have additional linear constraints which will be the same.

My question is the following: Is it possible to argue that the LP algorithm will always be faster than the QP algorithm given that we use the state of the art algorithms for each ?

Update: I realise that the solutions will not be the same. But assuming that I want to compare both approaches, I simply want to know which one will in general be faster. In practice I find LP to be faster. But I would like to know if this is a hard rule or does it simply come down to which algorithm I am using and the nature of the problem and constraints.

Comment: How are those equivalent optimization problems? If true, it would be like saying minimizing $\|x\|_2$ is the same as minimizing $\|x\|_1$, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you tell us anything about the other constraints?  Are you interested in actually solving some of these problems in practice?  If so, how big is $N$ and how many linear constraints are there?

Comment: To stress Kirill's point: As soon as there are additional constraints, these two formulations are *not* equivalent. So your question is one of modeling, not mathematics. (If there are no constraints, they are of course equivalent, both having the trivial solution $C=0$.)

Comment: The additional constraints will be the same in both cases. I realise the solutions will be different. As for $N$ it will be around 30.

Comment: Your problems are so tiny that they'll be easy to solve either way.

Comment: I know. But I need to solve thousands of these problems. In any case I was wondering if a general rule can be made.

Comment: I don't think there can be a general answer; it depends too much on the geometry of the problem (eigenvalues of $A$, (non-)strict complementarity of the constraints etc.)

Comment: Thousands of extremely cheap computations are still cheap. If this is the level of complexity you are worried about, then don't worry: a thousand, 30-variable problems should be solvable in a few seconds at most, with either formulation.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth there are $30^{2}=900$ variables, but the individual problems should still be solvable in well under one second.

Comment: @BrianBorchers - Oh, true, I missed the square. Still, even 900 is a small problem.

Comment: If we set aside the specific problem, I think it remains an interesting problem whether a QP formulation is generally faster than an LP formulation.